# keep getting IndexError: list index out of rangeIndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to make the code check if the entered username and password are valid by comparing them to the content of a text file, but I keep getting this `IndexError: list index out of range`.

The problem is the code was working fine and then for unknown reason it's stopped.

Here is the python code

```
class Login_Screen(MDScreen):

    def log_in(self):
     username = self.ids.username.text
     password = self.ids.pwd.text
     login_btn = self.ids.login_btn
     with open(r'D:\Downloads\GP\code\Hamster-App-master\libs\uix\baseclass\userinfo.txt','r') as info_file:
         read_file = csv.reader(info_file)
         for line in read_file:   
           if line[0]== username and line[1]== password:
            login_btn.disabled = False
            break
           else:
            break

         info_file.close()
```

and the text file only have 2 lines:

```
ola
123
```

I tried to use `for line in read_file` and `for row in read_file`.

Comment: Each line in the file only has one word on it, but your code is trying process it as though there were two — hence the `IndexError`.

Answer (score -1):

You made a for loop for 2 lines but for each line you ask for two arguments
try to make sure if there is a line

```
for line in read_file:   
    if line[0] and line[1]:
       if line[0]== username and if line[1]== password:
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent the IndexError because `line` is _not ever empty_, so the `if line` is useless. You need to check that `line` _has two elements_, because _that's_ what causes the error. Also `if ... and if ...` is a syntax error. You don't put two `if`s in a line.